# C# Xamarin Android, how to start activity from DLL, which was loaded runtime?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-activity, dll-injection

I'm trying to make an Android application that loads a DLL at runtime. Android application connects to server which returns DLL. Next step, application loads DLL into Assembly AppDomain

```
private IExecutor _executor { get; set; }

//...

private void LoadAssembly(string directoryPath)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.dll").Reverse())
    {
        try
        {
            var dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
            var types = dll.GetExportedTypes();
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IExecutor)))
                {
                    _executor = (IExecutor)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    _executor.UpdateText += Update;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("ERROR", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

IExecutor is the interface through which the DLL is called. When I try to start Activity from DLL an error occurs.

```
//...

// This is the method of dll that is called from MainActivity
public async Task Execute(object obj)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    if (obj is Activity activityContext)
    {
        activityContext.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                activityContext.StartActivity(typeof(DllActivity));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                UpdateText?.Invoke(ex.ToString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Stack trace

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: crc6408cf19efe5db9483.DllActivity ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "crc6408cf19efe5db9483.DllActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.autoupdating-7We2-rb7zFnUk2MxOGAdOQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.autoupdating-7We2-rb7zFnUk2MxOGAdOQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.companyname.autoupdating-7We2-rb7zFnUk2MxOGAdOQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00018] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x0003d] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.Type type) [0x00080] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Class.FromType (System.Type type) [0x00022] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Android.Content.Intent..ctor (Android.Content.Context packageContext, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Android.Content.Context.StartActivity (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at TestLibrary.DllClass+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Execute>b__0 () [0x00000] in D:\VisualProjects\TestLibrary\DllClass.cs:22 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: crc6408cf19efe5db9483.DllActivity
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6980)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "crc6408cf19efe5db9483.DllActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.autoupdating-7We2-rb7zFnUk2MxOGAdOQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.autoupdating-7We2-rb7zFnUk2MxOGAdOQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.companyname.autoupdating-7We2-rb7zFnUk2MxOGAdOQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 14 more
```

I understand that the error occurs due to the fact that Android Manifest does not have such an activity. And the activity search is done in the app package. But I don’t know how to fix it, I really hope for your help. Finally, I need to be able to quickly load new activities with new functionality. Thank you!

Comment: This is because the Activity needs to be declared in the project.If you put the StartActivity function in a method in the DLL, and then call the method in the xamarin project. Will it work?

Comment: The Activity needs to be defined in the AndroidManifest, otherwise you cannot launch it.

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT I can create an activity only from application context. I edited the method of DLL, but the error remained.`Application.Context.StartActivity(typeof(DllActivity));`

Comment: @Cheesebaron As I understand it, it is not possible to define a new activity at runtime, right?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks for the answer, most likely this is the answer to the question, and I will need to reconsider the approach to creating a program.

Comment: Use fragments instead maybe?

Comment: @Cheesebaron This is good advice, thank you!